# Can i buy US PS3 DLC on a PS4 with PayPal?

Tags: psn

Playstation has recently added on the PS4 the ability to use PayPal to pay for stuff on the Playstation Store. I am wondering, can i buy US PS3/PS Vita DLC using an Australian PS4 with a US PSN Account and pay with PayPal?

The reason why I ask this is because in the past US PSN would reject all Australian Debit Cards. I'm hoping to be able to download US DLC using PayPal to pay rather than having to get ripped off getting US Voucher Cards off 3rd party sellers (like paying US $75 for a $50 card)

Comment: wouldn't Sony use the billing address provided by PayPal, and reject an Aus CC for the US store in the same way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is a bit complicated. First, as far as I know, you can't buy PS3 or Vita content in the store on PS4. It will only show Playstation 4 games and DLC, except for free PS3 games with PS Plus, which you can claim, but not download on PS4. At least those are the only things displayed on my PS4.

Now, since you can't download these things on PS4, I'm not sure if this answers your question, but paying with PayPal has been possible on PS3 for quite some time.

I have a UK PSN account while living in Germany, and when Sony introduced PayPal as a payment option, I tried to add funds to my account with PayPal (with no Credit Card). The Payment got cancelled almost immediately, presumably because of my German address. I don't know if this is the case with Australia/USA, but it is likely to be the same.

So there is currently no direct way to add funds to an account of a different region than you are living in, except for buying PSN cards from that region.

Comment: i didn't know that the PS3 could accept PayPal Payment aswell, i only heard about the PS4, however since the purpose of buying PS3 and Vita DLC on the PS4 was because of PayPal and that from your answer even when you use PayPal on the PS3 it's still rejected it answered my question aswell

Answer (score -1):

You could just make a new paypal account making sure you make it a US address when signing up :)

Check out [this](http://www.guidingtech.com/25832/add-funds-paypal-us-playstation/) link for more detailed explanation

Basically

1) You must create a US psn account and make it your main account so that whenever you purchase anything on the US psn store it will be playable on all other accounts. Make sure you have a valid US address, post code etc.

2) Create a new paypal account. Use the same address as you did for the US PSN account.

Copied from [link](http://www.guidingtech.com/25832/add-funds-paypal-us-playstation/)--->

"Usually, after you submit this information, Paypal will ask you to link your bank account, your credit card or a debit card to your Paypal account. This is not mandatory (in fact, whether you link a card or an account, they will also need to be from the U.S., which will make things even more difficult for you). But as you can see from the screenshot below, this is not necessary at all."

Comment: Please summarize the linked information in your answer.  That way, if ever the page goes down, your answer is still good.